# NSDateformatter incompatible format

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Tried almost everything and get null,
the format I pass as parameter 'NSString' : `WED 13-11-2013`

```
-(NSDate*)stringToDate:(NSString*)dateString{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, d-LLLL-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
//    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, dd-MM-yyyy"];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd-MM-yyyy"];

//    NSString *str = [dateString stringByAppendingString:@" 09:00:00 +0000"];
//    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];


    return date;
}
```

Comment: Remove comma. it should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi try that it works for me:

```
-(NSDate*)stringToDate:(NSString*)dateString{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE dd-MM-yyyy ";
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    return date
}
```

Comment: Funny, that gives me also (null).

Comment: Do you run it under iOS 7?

Comment: Upps. Nope, OS X 10.9 (missed that)